# Plotting Contrasting graph(s) from a dataset using R

Tags: r, graph, dataset

I have a set of data (1000+ animals) from two seasons (winter and summer) and would like to demonstrate the differences in the gestation length (days) pattern in these two seasons. My data is similar to this:

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
season <- c(1,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,1)
gest <- c(114,NA,123,116,NA,120,110,NA,116,119)

data <- cbind(id,season,gest)
```

I would like to have something like this:

http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/graphics/55078149a733dd1a0b42a57faf847036.png

OR any similar form of graph that would give me a good contrast.

Thank you for all your help,

Bazon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That particular plot that you linked used `ggplot2`. I'm not really good at using it, so I'll show you how to do it with base graphics

```
data <- as.data.frame(data)
d1 <- density(data$gest[which(data$season==1)], na.rm=TRUE)
d2 <- density(data$gest[which(data$season==2)], na.rm=TRUE)
plot(d1, ylim=c(0, max(d1$y,d2$y)), xlim=range(c(d1$x, d2$x)),
  main="Length of gestation", xlab="Length (days)", col="blue", lwd=2)
polygon(d1$x, d1$y, col=rgb(0, 0, 1, 0.5), lty=0)
points(d2, t="l", col="red", lwd=2)
polygon(d2$x, d2$y, col=rgb(1, 0, 0, 0.5), lty=0)
```

Alternatively check out the `densityplot` function of the `lattice` package, although I'm not sure how to fill in the lines.

PS: is your dataset that small? Density plots are probably NOT the way to go if that is the case (a scatterplot would be better)

**EDIT**

If you want to do this with histograms you can do something like:

```
hist(data$gest[which(data$season==1)], main="Length of gestation", 
    xlab="Length (days)", col=rgb(0, 0, 1, 0.5))
# Note the add=TRUE parameter to superimpose the histograms
hist(data$gest[which(data$season==2)], col=rgb(1, 0, 0, 0.5), add=TRUE)
```

Comment: hi nico, thanks for the great help. I only have ~1000 animals and like you said density plot are probably not the way. Would like to try histograms but also need help in the codes.

Comment: @Bazon: I guess 1000 animals is not that bad for density plot. Anyway, I updated my answer for histograms.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(id=id,season=season,gest=gest)
qplot(gest,data=df,geom="density",fill=season,alpha=I(0.2))
```

This should give something similar to that example, but you may want to play with the `alpha` parameter to get the transparency right.

Answer (score 1):

There is a chart type commonly used to show demographics data, and in particular for directly contrasting two groups in which you wish to emphasize the comparison of *subgroups* that comprise both groups which are identical to each other along some or all variables other than  In the demographics context, the most common application is age structure of males versus females. This seems like it might be a good candidate to effectively visualize your data.

The plot shown below was created using the Base graphics package in R and the (excellent) R Package [SVGAnnotatio](http://www.omegahat.org/SVGAnnotation/)n, by Duncan Temple Lang, to create the interactive elements (by re-rendering the image in SVG and post-processing the resultant XML).

(Although the plot was created using R and SVGAnnotate, the image below is from a UK Government [Site](http://www.statistics.gov.uk/populationestimates/svg_pyramid/ew/pyramid4_3.svg)).

[image]

Comment: doug, would you be able to post some code to generate that? Also, what's up with those spikes at age 15 and 40???? Reminds me of this article I was reading the other day: http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2010/10/old-wives.html

Comment: Hi doug, would you be able to generate the codes for that amazing graph above based on the example data provided.

Comment: It's cool-looking, but I actually think the density plots above would be better for comparing your (Bazon's) data.